# Read binary file from a generic path in java

Tags: java, file

I am writing a library that takes a file path which can be either local or classpath or remote (simple http, no authentication). Is there any such generic utility that receives such string path and return the file binary content? The example paths are:

- c:/mydirectory/file.jpg
- classpath:com/example/file.jpg
- http://example.com/file.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use URL and create URLConnection to get the input stream from file or web link.

```
package ch.p1gu;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        URL fileUrl = new URL("file:///home/p1gu/tmp/test.txt");
        URL webUrl = new URL("http://pastebin.com/RdVdQVdC");
        URLConnection ucWeb = webUrl.openConnection();
        URLConnection ucFile=fileUrl.openConnection();

        DataInputStream disWeb  = new DataInputStream(ucWeb.getInputStream());
        DataInputStream disFile = new DataInputStream(ucFile.getInputStream());

        System.out.println(disFile.readUTF());
        System.out.println(disWeb.readUTF());

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```